# How to put a div below in another div (overlapping another div in between)?

Tags: css

Now I can just put the ABC div to the right but below Body div. How do I put ABC div below Header div? Overlapping is needed.

```html
    <div style="width:500px;margin:0 auto;">
        <div style="background-color:yellow;height:100px">Header</div>
        <div style="background-color:aquamarine; height: 400px">Body</div>
        <div style="background-color:red;width:100px;margin-left:auto">ABC</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you sketch what you need? You want "Body" and "ABC" to be in one row?

Comment: Yeah same row.  Overlapping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have added 2 answers. 1st is for external stylesheet , 2nd is for inline styling (just like how you wrote your code).

Firstly, don't use inline styling. If possible, always use external stylesheet.

Now, for your question, use `relative` position for the parent and `absolute` for the child. In this case, parent is your main container and child is that ABC div.

Try this:

```css
#container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.header {
  background-color:yellow;
  height:100px
}

.body {
  background-color:aquamarine;
  height: 400px;
}

.abc {
  background-color:red;
  width:100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="body">Body</div>
  <div class="abc">ABC</div>
</div>
```

**Explanation:**

Since your `.header` is 100px, you can set the `.abc` to `top: 100px;` and set the `right: 0` to move it to the extreme right within the parent since `.abc` is absolutely positioned to its parent.

If you are only allowed to use inline-styling, then try this:

```html
<div style="width:500px;margin:0 auto;position:relative;">
  <div style="background-color:yellow;height:100px">Header</div>
  <div style="background-color:aquamarine; height: 400px">Body</div>
  <div style="background-color:red;width:100px;position:absolute;top:100px;right:0;">ABC</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah,  I know shouldn't use inline.  Just trying to simplify and shorten it for this question.  Thanks for the code with explanation.

Comment: You're welcome Steve, thank you for accepting. Cheers buddy.

Answer (score 1):

I added float: right to place the ABC div on the BODY div (overlap) and interchanged the position of the div BODY and ABC

```html
<div style="width:500px;margin:0 auto;">
    <div style="background-color:yellow;height:100px">Header</div>
    <div style="background-color:red;width:100px;float: right;">ABC</div>
     <div style="background-color:aquamarine; height: 400px">Body</div>
</div>
```

go to https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp for more information

Comment: See now there is no negative value

Answer (score 1):

To make layout you can use flexbox utilities. It's the most common and probably the easiest way to make layout.

I hope this is what you need.

For more infos check [DOCS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout)

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container-fluid{
  width:100%;
}
header{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background:yellow
}
.row{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.col-left{
  width:100%;
  flex:0 0 75%;
  max-width:75%;
  background:blue;
  height:100px
}
.col-right{
  width:100%;
  flex:0 0 25%;
  max-width:25%;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <header></header>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-left"></div>
    <div class="col-right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: blue and red should overlapping each other. red is on top of blue. red's height is lesser compare to blue. Gosi's answer is what I want. Not sure if flexbox can do the same

Comment: You can place red inside blue and use flexbox and `justify-content:flex-end`. It depends on what you need. You can also use `position:absolute`.